# Error in <cstdio> when <string> is included

Tags: iphone, c++, gcc

```
_gnu_cxx::snprintf has not been declared
```

when I include string in my cpp. This error is in  on this line:

```
using ::__gnu_cxx::snprintf;
```

cstdio is include in this order:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/string:47,
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/char_traits.h:46,
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:70,
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:45,
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:45,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding    #define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_DYNAMIC 1 in my header.